# Covering map of what order?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

How can you see in this picture

of what order the covering maps be?
Well I look for one with a degree of two and one with a degree of four.
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Count vertices. [And forget about the rest: $a,b,  a^2,a^{-1},...$]

Answer (score 2):

These are covering spaces for $S^1\vee S^1$.  The edges labeled '$a$' map to one of the $S^1$'s and the edges labeled '$b$' map to the other.  You only need to count the number of occurrences of '$a$', or '$b$'.  For example, $(1)$ has two $a$'s and two $b$'s and is thus a double cover.

Comment: I just know that $a^-1$ means you are going in the opposite direction. but what does $a^2$ means? and do I have to count a^2 like two a's or like one?

Comment: I just meant to count the $a$'s and $b$'s in the picture.  The stuff in the brackets is telling you to which subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}* \mathbb{Z}$ the particular covering corresponds.